# Call rest endpoint based on a checkbox being ticked

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, rest

I have this `React` component:

```
import * as React from 'react';

import './Pless.css';

interface Props {
    handleClose: () => void;
    showPless: boolean;
}

export class Pless extends React.Component<Props> {

    constructor(props: Props) {
        super(props);
    }
 
    render() {
        const { showPless } = this.props;
        const showHideClassName = showPless ? 'show-div' : 'display-none';
        console.log(this.props);
        return (
            <div className={showHideClassName}>
            <div id="mypless" className="pless">
    
                <div className="pless-content">
                    <div className="pless-header">
                    <span className="close" onClick={this.props.handleClose}><u>Close</u> X</span>
                    <h2 />
                    </div>
                    <div className="pless-body">
                        <h2 className="content-header">Header</h2>
                        <p className="main-text">Text:</p>
                        
                        <ol className="main-text">
                            <li>List item</li>
                        </ol>
                        
                        </div><div className="pless-footer">
                            <label htmlFor="isPless">
                                <input id="isPless" name="isPless" type="checkbox" /> Relevant text 
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }   
}
```

When this popup appears I want to call a rest endpoint if the checkbox is ticked and close is clicked. If the checkbox is not ticked and close is pressed, no call is made. I have the checkbox displaying and it can be ticked/unticked but I don't know how to call the endpoint based on it being selected. How is this done?

Comment: On the click event of the close button you may check if you had a ticked checkbox and do what you want.

Comment: `onClick`  already runs `this.props.handleClose`. Is it possible for it to run an additional function which checks the checkbox status?

Answer (score 0):

First you need a state for your checkbox input. Something like:

```
const [boxState, setBoxState] = useState(false);
```

then you need to add a `change` event on the checkbox input:

```
onChange={toggleHandler}
```

The handler will be something like:

```
const toggleHandler = () => setBoxState(prevState => !prevState);
```

At this point in your click event for closing, you can reference the checkbox state. In your case you should have something like:

```
onClick={this.props.handleClose.bind(null, boxState)};
```

Now wherever the function `handleClose` is defined, you should modify it to accept this `boxState` argument which will be a boolean saying whether the checkbox was checked or not. Use this argument in an `if` statement to achieve what you want.

I wrote the following example hoping it helps:

```
import { useState } from 'react';

export function CheckBoxxx() {
  const [boxState, setBoxState] = useState(false);

  const toggleHandler = () => setBoxState(prevState => !prevState);

  const closeHandler = () => console.log(boxState ? 'Do something' : 'Do not');

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={closeHandler}>Close</button>
      <label>
        Check me
        <input
          name="isGoing"
          type="checkbox"
          onChange={toggleHandler}
        />
      </label>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried that but got this error. Could it be because I'm using React Component but the example uses hooks?

`Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app...`

Comment: Yes I used funcion based components and hooks in the example because I have never learnt to work with class based components. But the logic is still the same, you can implement it in your react version.